# Wordrpress. get_posts выводит только последний пост n-раз

Tags: php, wordpress

```
global $post;
$args = array(
    'category' => 2,
    'orderby' => 'DESC', 
    'numberposts'=> 6
);

$myposts = get_posts($args);

foreach ($myposts as $key=>$value) {
        setup_postdata($value);

        $wowClass = '';
        if ($key == 0 || $key == 5) {
           $wowClass = 'fadeInDownBig';
        }
    }
    //тут вывод html
    wp_reset_postdata();
```

Выводится последний добавленный пост 6 раз. Не понятно, что не так

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо  `$value` надо использовать глобальную переменную `$post`. Так работает `setup_postdata()`.

Comment: Благодарю, сработало)